# `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: qt, glibc

I want to install a QT library that is needed by another program in a Linux machine that I do not have a root access to. Instead I installed it on my machine which is an Ubuntu 12.04 which I have a root access. I then take the installed version to this other machine and start to install my new program that requires the Qt Libraries.

But I came across an error:

/home/test/qt/bin/qmake: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/test/local/qt/bin/qmake)

The "/lib/libc.so.6" is indeed exists in the new machine that I can not have access to.

How can I able to solve this hurdle ?

Kind regards
Yacob

Answer (score 0):

You have different libc versions in your computers. 
Your best option is to compile QT packages in the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get it running?

A hint has been added in the [Troubleshooting section of the website](http://gogs.io/docs/intro/troubleshooting.html#other):

> Solution: try `sudo apt-get -t testing install libc6-dev`.

You just have to add the respective repository to your apt sources before.

---

However this is not a good solution for me as i wouldn't do this on a production system. Unfortunately it's also not an alternative to use the docker version as the kernel in Debian 7 doesn't support LXC which is required by docker. The only way is to update to the kernel to the next version supported in the testing repo. Also not nice in a production environment.

http://doduck.com/docker-install-on-debian-7/